# How to disable button in NodeJs express?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, forms, express

I have the following form that is rendered and would like the `submit button` to be disabled upon the first click, to prevent the user from continuously clicking on it. If possible, I would like the submit button message to change from

> Im done

to

> Please wait...

Below is the view code

```
<!-- Send email and update user -->
<form method="post" action="/delivery/chooseBoxSelectedEmailUpdate">
  <input type="hidden" name="boxCommand" value="{{command}}">
  <input type="hidden" name="boxComport" value="{{comport}}">
  <input type="hidden" name="boxCubbyId" value="{{cubbyId}}">
  <input type="hidden" name="boxId" value="{{boxId}}">
  <input type="hidden" name="userHashtag" value="{{userHashtag}}">

  <button class="btn-primary-full" type="submit">
    <i class="fa fa-cube" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    &nbsp;I'm done
  </button>
</form>
```

Below is the render code

```
res.render('delivery/chooseBoxSelectedOpened', {
  title: 'Layoverbox',
  helpButtonURL: '/help/help-dropPackage',
  helpButtonTitle: 'Help',
  boxComport: comport,
  boxCommand: command,
  cubbyId: rows[i].cubby_id,
  boxId: boxSelectedValue
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

To make it easier to find the button's text, let's wrap it with a `<span/>` tag.

```
<button class="btn-primary-full" type="submit">
    <i class="fa fa-cube" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    &nbsp;<span>I'm done</span>
</button>
```

**JavaScript**

I am assuming you have written an `onsubmit` handler for your form.

Upon clicking on the submit button, before making your AJAX request, disable and set the text of the submit button.

Once you get back a response from your AJAX request, in the `success` or `complete` handler, enable and reset the text of the submit button.

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // find and cache submit button within the form
        var button = $('button[type=submit]', this);
        // disable and set the text
        button.prop('disabled', true).find('span').text("Please wait...");
        // make AJAX call
        $.ajax({
            // etc
            success: function (data) {
                button.prop('disabled', false).find('span').text("I'm done");
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by onsubmit handler. The view is rendered through hbs?

Comment: such as onsubmit="formSubmit()"?

Comment: When you click a submit button within a form, by default, the browser will post the form data and redirect to the URL (specified in the form's `action` attribute). So, anything you do on the page afterwards is useless because your page will be gone. **In order to remain on the same page after submitting the form**, you need to attach an [`onsubmit` event](http://help.dottoro.com/ljppxrti.php) to your `form` element and use AJAX to submit your form.

Comment: In jQuery, you use [`submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) or [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach an `onsubmit` event handler. As well, you use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [any of its shorthand methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/) to make AJAX request. Because you are using hbs (handlebars?), you may need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). I edited my answer to show how you would do it using event delegation.